# iOS 11public beta 7 getUserMedia not working using ionic2?

Tags: ionic-framework, getusermedia, ios11

Apple released a statement that getUserMedia will be fully functional on iOS 11. After installing iOS 11 Beta version 7, I do not get any stream message using below code write on ionic2:

```
       var constraints = {
            audio: false,
            video: { facingMode: 'user' }
        };

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(
            function success(stream) {
                  console.log('====mid=====');
                  console.log(stream);
                //video.srcObject = stream;
            }
        ).catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `getUserMedia` is only supported in Safari and not WKWebView or UIWebView in iOS 11.

http://www.openradar.me/33571214